# request..args.get stores nothing

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have the following code. These code supposed to get user's input and processed in python. All these are supposed to run in the same webpage.

I have tried all possible function under `flask.request`.

Inside the python file,

```
app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/detection",methods=['GET'])
def detections():
    code=request.args.get('code',default='',type=str)
    print(code)
    ide=Lang_Dec(code)
    lang=ide.get_lang()
    print(lang)
    return jsonify({'html':lang})
```

Inside the html file,

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <textarea class="codemirror-textarea" id='code'></textarea>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id='butt'>Guess the function!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card" >
                        <h5 class="card-header">Detected Language</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6 class="card-title" id='lang'></h6>
                            <p class="card-text">Percentages</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" >
                            <h5 class="card-header">IDE OUTPUT</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text" id='ide'></p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var code = $(".codemirror-textarea")[0];
                var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
                    lineNumbers : true,
                    theme : "duotone-dark",
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#butt').click(function(){
                    var code=$('#code').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"/detection",
                        type: "get",
                        data:{code:code},
                        success:function(response){
                            $('#lang').html(response.html);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr){
                            //do smtg
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

The Python is supposed to get the user input from the `textarea`, but it turns out that the Python script only getting a `-`.

Comment: `"code"` here should be the `name` of the textarea, instead of (or as well as) the id

Comment: Do you mean changing the `class="codemirror-textarea"` to `class="code"`?

Comment: Neither, I mean adding `name="code"` to the element

Comment: It still didn't show up in the Python script. still print out an `-`

Comment: Apologies, I just looked at your html/js more closely, you don't need the `name` attribute because you're not submitting the data as a form, but "by hand". I can't see any obvious problems with this in mind, I'm afraid, but I'll have another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Python or Flask issue, you have not wrapped your textarea inside a form, and the [CodeMirror Documentation](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_static) suggests the following (emphasis mine):

> CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea: TextAreaElement, ?config: object)
>
> This method provides another way to initialize an editor. It takes a
>   textarea DOM node as first argument and an optional configuration
>   object as second. It will replace the textarea with a CodeMirror
>   instance, and **wire up the form of that textarea (if any) to make sure**
>   **the editor contents are put into the textarea when the form is**
>   **submitted**. The text in the textarea will provide the content for the
>   editor.

Try and confirm this with a simple form:

```
<form action='detection'>
    <textarea id='code' name='code'></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Serving locally, submitting the form with some random text input yields the following:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2019 22:50:04] "GET /detection?code=dfgdfgdfgggggggggg HTTP/1.1"

So in your case, it looks like you need to call `cm.save()` prior to your Ajax request, at least that is what a quick glance at the documentation suggests to me.

So a quick and dirty fix to your code would look like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var code = document.getElementById('code');
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
            lineNumbers : true,
            theme : "duotone-dark",
        });
       $('#butt').click(function(){
            editor.save(); // this is where the textarea content gets updated
            var c=$('#code').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/detection",
                type: "get",
                data:{code:c},
                success:function(response){
                    $('#lang').html(response.html);
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    //do smtg
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! But, when i click the button, obviously it will lead to the detection page, which I do not wish to, is there any quick fix?

Comment: @H.Vin The first part of the answer covers the form submit variant, I mainly included that for better explaining the issue. The last code example is the Ajax variant, you should be able to more or less just use that code instead of the current scripting in your question and get it to work.